# Looking for a Sample IRS AIR XML file to use on the ISS-UI AATS 2016 site

Tags: xml, xsd, irs

I have tried the official copy referenced in the submission and composition reference guide with no luck (below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ACAUIBusinessHeader xmlns:p="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader"
xmlns:acaBusHeader="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader"
xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0"
xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurityutility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader IRSACAUserInterfaceHeaderMessage.xsd">
<acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>
<UniqueTransmissionId>token</UniqueTransmissionId>
<irs:Timestamp>2016-12-31T12:00:00</irs:Timestamp>
</acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>
<ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
<PaymentYr>2015</PaymentYr>
<PriorYearDataInd>0</PriorYearDataInd>
<irs:EIN>EIN</irs:EIN>
<TransmissionTypeCd>O</TransmissionTypeCd>
<TestFileCd>TestFileCd</TestFileCd>
<OriginalReceiptId>OriginalReceiptId</OriginalReceiptId>
<TransmitterForeignEntityInd>0</TransmitterForeignEntityInd>
<TransmitterNameGrp>
<BusinessNameLine1Txt>BusinessNameLine1Txt</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
<BusinessNameLine2Txt>BusinessNameLine2Txt</BusinessNameLine2Txt>
</TransmitterNameGrp>
<CompanyInformationGrp>
<CompanyNm>CompanyNm</CompanyNm>
<MailingAddressGrp>
<USAddressGrp>
<AddressLine1Txt>AddressLine1Txt</AddressLine1Txt>
<AddressLine2Txt>AddressLine2Txt</AddressLine2Txt>
<irs:CityNm>CityNm</irs:CityNm>
<USStateCd>AL</USStateCd>
<irs:USZIPCd>USZIPCd</irs:USZIPCd>
<irs:USZIPExtensionCd>USZIPExtensionCd</irs:USZIPExtensionCd>
</USAddressGrp>
</MailingAddressGrp>
<ContactNameGrp>
<irs:PersonFirstNm>PersonFirstNm</irs:PersonFirstNm>
<irs:PersonMiddleNm>PersonMiddleNm</irs:PersonMiddleNm>
<irs:PersonLastNm>PersonLastNm</irs:PersonLastNm>
<irs:SuffixNm>SuffixNm</irs:SuffixNm>
</ContactNameGrp>
<ContactPhoneNum>ContactPhoneNum</ContactPhoneNum>
</CompanyInformationGrp>
<VendorInformationGrp>
<VendorCd>VendorCd</VendorCd>
<ContactNameGrp>
<irs:PersonFirstNm>PersonFirstNm</irs:PersonFirstNm>
<irs:PersonMiddleNm>PersonMiddleNm</irs:PersonMiddleNm>
<irs:PersonLastNm>PersonLastNm</irs:PersonLastNm>
<irs:SuffixNm>SuffixNm</irs:SuffixNm>
</ContactNameGrp>
<ContactPhoneNum>ContactPhoneNum</ContactPhoneNum>
</VendorInformationGrp>
<TotalPayeeRecordCnt>0</TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
<TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</TotalPayerRecordCnt>
<SoftwareId>SoftwareId</SoftwareId>
<FormTypeCd>1094/1095B</FormTypeCd>
<irs:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</irs:BinaryFormatCd>
<irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>ChecksumAugmentationNum</irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
<irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>0</irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>
<DocumentSystemFileNm>DocumentSystemFileNm</DocumentSystemFileNm>
</ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
</p:ACAUIBusinessHeader>
```

Of course, when you sub in your own information and submit this on the ISS-UI AATS 2016 Site it just says:

```
1 error has occurred. See below for more information. If the problem continues, please contact us.

Our system has detected a potential threat in the file you are attempting to transmit and it can not be transmitted. Please check the file and try again.
```

After running the sample file against the XSDs, it shows that the timestamp format is wrong (it needs a 'Z' at the end) and the prefixes on '`irs:PersonFirstNm`', '`irs:PersonLastNm`', '`irs:PersonMiddleNm`' should not be there.

After I changed that, the file passes XSD validation just fine, but the same error is shown:

```
1 error has occurred. See below for more information. If the problem continues, please contact us.

Our system has detected a potential threat in the file you are attempting to transmit and it can not be transmitted. Please check the file and try again.
```

Is there anyone out there currently working against the IRS AIR ACA system, and does anyone have a copy of the manifest file that they have sent in that they know works? I have pinged the IRS helpdesk for more information, but they take 7 business days to get back to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

2016 Version of the Test Scenarios have been posted here:

https://blog.boomtax.com/2016-irs-air-test-scenario-xml-iss-ui/

2015 Version of AATS Test Scenarios

https://blog.boomtax.com/irs-air-test-scenario-xml-sample-files/

Comment: I've never wanted so badly to upvote an answer 12 times as I do right now.

Comment: Sadly enough all of these are now out of date and they are ONLY for the C's. They ARE a nice example though, even if they aren't good enough to pass the test scenario transmissions.

Answer (score 4):

Ken,

I am working on software for the 1094/1095C forms and just got my scenario 3 (3-0, 3-1, 3-2, 3-3) accepted.  I sent the IRS an email on Friday regarding their regex pattern for the UniqueTransmissionId.  I'm not sure if they fixed the pattern in their schema, but I had the same error as you last week.  My manifest file still doesn't validate against the published XSD.  However, today, I was able to get pass the error and both the manifest file and form data file were accepted via the UI channel.

Here's the accepted manifest file without my personal info.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ACAUIBusinessHeader xmlns:p="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader" xmlns:acaBusHeader="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader IRS-ACAUserInterfaceHeaderMessage.xsd ">
 <acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>
  <UniqueTransmissionId>719f5624-e78c-487e-a6ce-1686e9ff3f35:SYS12:AAAAA::T</UniqueTransmissionId>
  <irs:Timestamp>2015-12-14T20:54:42Z</irs:Timestamp>
 </acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>
 <ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
  <PaymentYr>2016</PaymentYr>
  <PriorYearDataInd>0</PriorYearDataInd>
  <irs:EIN>10digitEIN</irs:EIN>
  <TransmissionTypeCd>O</TransmissionTypeCd>
  <TestFileCd>T</TestFileCd>
  <TransmitterForeignEntityInd>0</TransmitterForeignEntityInd>
  <TransmitterNameGrp>
   <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Your Company Name</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
  </TransmitterNameGrp>
  <CompanyInformationGrp>
   <CompanyNm>YOUR COMPANY NAME</CompanyNm>
   <MailingAddressGrp>
    <USAddressGrp>
     <AddressLine1Txt>YOUR ADDRESS</AddressLine1Txt>
     <irs:CityNm>HOUSTON</irs:CityNm>
     <USStateCd>TX</USStateCd>
     <irs:USZIPCd>12345</irs:USZIPCd>
    </USAddressGrp>
   </MailingAddressGrp>
   <ContactNameGrp>
    <PersonFirstNm>YourFirstName</PersonFirstNm>
    <PersonMiddleNm>MiddleI</PersonMiddleNm>
    <PersonLastNm>YourLastName</PersonLastNm>
   </ContactNameGrp>
   <ContactPhoneNum>YourPhone</ContactPhoneNum>
  </CompanyInformationGrp>
  <VendorInformationGrp>
   <VendorCd>V</VendorCd>
   <ContactNameGrp>
    <PersonFirstNm>YourFirstName</PersonFirstNm>
    <PersonMiddleNm>MiddleI</PersonMiddleNm>
    <PersonLastNm>YourLastName</PersonLastNm>
   </ContactNameGrp>
   <ContactPhoneNum>YourPhone</ContactPhoneNum>
  </VendorInformationGrp>
  <TotalPayeeRecordCnt>3</TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
  <TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</TotalPayerRecordCnt>
  <SoftwareId>YourSoftwareId</SoftwareId>
  <FormTypeCd>1094/1095C</FormTypeCd>
  <irs:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</irs:BinaryFormatCd>
  <irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>e074db4e92ffddeac8d93a686a2a0e1d</irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
  <irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>13275</irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>
  <DocumentSystemFileNm>1094C_Request_AAAAA_20151214T205442000Z.xml</DocumentSystemFileNm>
 </ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
</p:ACAUIBusinessHeader>
```

I'm new to posting on here (my first response was actually deleted by the moderators), so please bear with me as I try to get the posting correct.

Comment: Unless these comments were in regard to something else, it looks like he's answered the question exactly. I'm going to diff this with what I've been testing and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Just checked this and I was able to submit my test scenarios with your changes. From what I can see the main differences were:

Comment: PaymentYr = 2016. My vendor code is set to I, but that didn't seem to make a difference. Now that it's in the system, I see error code AIRSH100 saying XML schema validation has failed. I will do some more research and report back.

Comment: @CNConsulting, Could you post your Scenario 3 form data XML too? We are having a similar issue and the IRS is less than helpful troubleshooting.

Comment: We found the 10 digit EIN was our problem, removing the hyphen (which IRS specifies should be included) got us past the initial error of "Our system has detected a potential threat".