# Error on Sample Manifest IRS AIR XML file to use on the ISS-UI AATS 2016 site

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, irs

I uploaded the manifest below to test for the sample IRS manifest but got the error below:

1 error has occurred. See below for more information. If the problem continues, please contact us.

[TPE 1105] Our system has detected a potential threat in the Manifest file you are attempting to transmit and it cannot be transmitted. This may be due to malformed XML. Please review the XML standards outlined in Section 3 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located here, correct any issues on the Manifest file, and try again.

Can someone help tell me the error in my manifest or send me a 2016 sample test data manifest upload?  My XML detail is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<p:ACAUIBusinessHeader xmlns:p="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader IRS-ACAUserInterfaceHeaderMessage.xsd" xmlns:acaBusHeader="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">


-<acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>

<UniqueTransmissionId>2c1af558-c5eb-11e5-9912-ba0be0483c18:SYS12:AAAAA::T</UniqueTransmissionId>

<irs:Timestamp>2016-03-14T04:59:20Z</irs:Timestamp>

</acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>


-<ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>

<PaymentYr>2016</PaymentYr>

<PriorYearDataInd>0</PriorYearDataInd>

<irs:EIN>EIN</irs:EIN>

<TransmissionTypeCd>O</TransmissionTypeCd>

<TestFileCd>T</TestFileCd>

<TransmitterForeignEntityInd>0</TransmitterForeignEntityInd>


-<TransmitterNameGrp>

<BusinessNameLine1Txt>COMPANY NAME</BusinessNameLine1Txt>

</TransmitterNameGrp>


-<CompanyInformationGrp>

<CompanyNm>Selitestthree</CompanyNm>


-<MailingAddressGrp>


-<USAddressGrp>

<AddressLine1Txt>555 TEST AVE</AddressLine1Txt>

<irs:CityNm>CITY</irs:CityNm>

<USStateCd>CA</USStateCd>

<irs:USZIPCd>40404</irs:USZIPCd>

</USAddressGrp>

</MailingAddressGrp>


-<ContactNameGrp>

<PersonFirstNm>TYLER</PersonFirstNm>

<PersonLastNm>JUICE</PersonLastNm>

</ContactNameGrp>

<ContactPhoneNum>5673628260</ContactPhoneNum>

</CompanyInformationGrp>


-<VendorInformationGrp>

<VendorCd>V</VendorCd>


-<ContactNameGrp>

<PersonFirstNm>JUSTINE</PersonFirstNm>

<PersonLastNm>GROUP</PersonLastNm>

</ContactNameGrp>

<ContactPhoneNum>6260550000</ContactPhoneNum>

</VendorInformationGrp>

<TotalPayeeRecordCnt>3</TotalPayeeRecordCnt>

<TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</TotalPayerRecordCnt>

<SoftwareId>2T89437395</SoftwareId>

<FormTypeCd>1094/1095C</FormTypeCd>

<irs:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</irs:BinaryFormatCd>

<irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>76ev4atu59416efb620a0e1ea4fc6753</irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>

<irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>12</irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>

<DocumentSystemFileNm>1094C_Request_AAAAA_20160303T085650785Z.xml</DocumentSystemFileNm>

</ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>

</p:ACAUIBusinessHeader>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the UI channel.  However, I can see that your XML is not well-formed.  For example, on the grouping elements, you have dash/hyphen character; this character should not be there.

For example:

```
-<TransmitterNameGrp>
```

should be:

```
<TransmitterNameGrp>
```

Perhaps this link ([Looking for a Sample IRS AIR XML file to use on the ISS-UI AATS 2016 site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34233592/5286901)) will help with the UI channel submission.

Answer (score 0):

Your Transmission ID appears to be in a different format than the standardized format I have successfully followed. The UUID in particular. 
For example: `550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000`

To increase to the next sequence if re-submitting to correct mistakes, you can increase `446655440000` to `446655440001`. Not sure how you will increase your unique transmission ID. Here is your ID:
`2c1af558-c5eb-11e5-9912-ba0be0483c18:SYS12:AAAAA::T`

Here is a sample from IRS Publication 5165:
`550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000:SYS12:BB002::T`